# How to make custom .exe of a Windows application in c#?

Tags: c#

How can I make custom .exe of a Windows application in c#?

Comment: What do you mean by "custom .exe"? You'll need to provide a *lot* more details if you want to get useful answers.

Comment: Do you want to give your application a custom *icon*?

Answer (score 2):

Just create new project in visual studio with type "Windows Forms Application" or "Console Application". And the output will be "EXE" :-)